# Margins on "Feed" screen way too large

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I recently opened the SE Android app on my phone, and it opened to the "Feed" screen. However, the margins on the right are way too large.

They take up way too much space (>50% in total).

They should be scaled down to something smaller - like 8% each - so that more then 3 words can be displayed per line.

[image: Picture of margins 2]